# php importance of a number in a set of numbers

Tags: php, algorithm, numbers

I have a set of numbers e.g.

```
$input = array(1, 4, 7, 4, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2, 8, 7, 7, 4, 5, 3);
```

I am trying to work out the importance of each number based on the following rule:

> As the sequence gets longer the numbers get less significant, and each time a number is mentioned then it will improve the relevance (how much depends on its position in the 
>   sequence).

I am expecting something like:

```
Array(
   '4' => 90%
   '1' => 75%
   '7' => 60%
   ....
)
```

So 4 is the most inportant, followed by 1 and then 7 etc. Note that the output is completely fabricated but gives in indication that 4 should be the most important. I believe I want some kind of linear solution.

Comment: Can you add some actual numbers? How will relevance be improved, according to what rule?

Comment: I'm not sure what I am missing, i have listed a set of numbers in my question, the number of the left being the most importance and going down in importance as the sequence gets longer.

Comment: @Lizard yeah, but by what formula will the importance be improved when a number is mentioned? ... edit: ah, no, I understand now. I thought there was an additional quirk that isn't there

Comment: We aren't sure if the numbers you show are pre or post run. We also are not sure how much the position and duplication of numbers in the sequence matters. Having the pre and post arrays will help us understand.

Comment: Ok, given that input, what might you expect as output (not necessarally ranked, just the order of output and the rationale behind it.  What would you expect out of `1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1`?  What about `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4`?

Comment: I have added an expected output to the question

Comment: How can 4 be more important when the position and occurrences of 1 overrides 4? How do you compute relevance? Should the weights be linear or exponential? My solution below addresses the latter.

Comment: linear as exponential would be far too weighted.

Comment: is it a finite Sequence of numbers?

Comment: @Lizard I think you need to have some sort of weighting formula in mind that's different from what we're all thinking, as almost any method with the input you've given will result in 1 having the highest relevance, followed by 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 2, 5, 3.

Comment: @shevski No it isn't The list of numbers will vary each time it is analysed

Comment: @Lizard your input is a finite array ? or Sequence of numbers which length is unknown?

Comment: Sequence of numbers which length is unknown

Comment: @Lizard: My solution magnifies my concern. `[4,1,1,1]` will result in `Array([4]=>4,[1]=>6)` so the number of 1's will outweigh 4. But that's the reason why we need clarification on weight system because `[4,1,1]` will result in `Array([4]=>3,[1]=>2)`. So which prevails in this case? position or count?

Comment: Notice also that @bpneal's solution has `[1]` ahead of `[8]` while mine is reversed because assigning weights and giving position or count more importance than the other can have significant impact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more of what you were thinking? Answer based on stillstanding

```
$numbers = array(1, 4, 7, 4, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2, 8, 7, 7, 4, 5, 3);
$weight = array();
$count = count($numbers);

for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
  if (!isset($weight[$numbers[$i]])) $weight[$numbers[$i]] = 1;
  $weight[$numbers[$i]] += $count + pow($count - $i, 2);
}

$max = array_sum($weight);
foreach ($weight as &$w) {
  $w = ($w / $max) * 100;
}

arsort($weight);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 34.5997286296
    [7] => 17.3677069199
    [1] => 16.3500678426
    [8] => 10.0407055631
    [9] => 9.29443690638
    [6] => 5.42740841248
    [2] => 4.40976933514
    [5] => 1.35685210312
    [3] => 1.15332428765
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers=array(1, 4, 7, 4, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2, 8, 7, 7, 4, 5, 3);
$weight=array();
$count=count($numbers);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    if (!isset($weight[$numbers[$i]]))
        $weight[$numbers[$i]]=1;
    $weight[$numbers[$i]]*=$count-$i;
}
var_dump($weight);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 15
    [4] => 5040
    [7] => 260
    [9] => 11
    [8] => 54
    [6] => 8
    [2] => 7
    [5] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

Comment: The problem with this is i would expect 4 to to be the most important not 1. Do you agree?

Comment: Your statement is true only if you compute the relevance in a linear fashion, which means there's a possibility that the relevance of two numbers will collide.

Comment: It appears that linear is what I am after then. What would you change in your example?

Comment: I think there is no way for [4,1,1,...,1] array to let 1's value to pass 4.

Comment: `[4,1,1,1]` will result in `Array([4]=>4,[1]=>6)` so the number of 1's will outweigh 4. But that's the reason why we need clarification on OP's weight system because `[4,1,1]` will result in `Array([4]=>3,[1]=>2)`. So which prevails in this case? position or count?

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is fairly simplistic, but I think it accomplishes what you're looking for.

Given that you have the sequence you described above and it is stored in an array called `$sequence`

```
$a = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($sequence);$i++)
{
   //calculate the relevance = 1/position in array
   $relevance = 1/($i+1);

   //add $relevance to the value of $a[$sequence[$i]]
   if(array_key_exists((string)$sequence[$i],$a))
       $a[(string)$sequence[$i]] += $relevance;
   else
       $a[(string)$sequence[$i]] = $relevance;
}
return $a;
```